# shell script array to store 256 ASCII characters

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question about how to initialize an array to store the 256 ASCII characters in bash. I know 65 is A, 97 is a, but I cannot list them one by one. Thanks

Comment: Please note that ASCII only defines 128 characters.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What is it that you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: sorry, I mean with the extended codes.

Comment: There is one character you can never store in any bash variable: The null byte `\0`. Is it ok to just skip this one or use the empty string instead?

Comment: @TianZhao The term ‘extended ASCII’ can mean many different things. Which set of characters, _exactly_, do you mean? And once again, for what purpose?

Comment: when I google ASCII, I see two tables and the total is 256 characters. I don't really know ASCII characters, but I need the set of all the letters and special characters.

Comment: The characters depend on the encoding. If you for instance compare the encodings for [iso-8859-1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) and [iso-8859-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-14), you see that they differ. Perhaps you want a file which contains the successions of bytes with values 0 to 255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to construct all the possible `\x` escapes and `printf` them to get the characters.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
chars=()
for i in {0..255} ; do
    chars+=("$(printf "\x$(printf %x $i)")")
done
```

Note that it doesn't work for `$'\x0'`, ${chars[0]} will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can generate a lookup table this way:

```
mapfile -s 1 -td '' array < <(printf %b\\0 \\x{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}})
```

or this way:

```
mapfile -s 1 -td '' array < <(printf %b\\0 $(printf '\\x%x ' {0..255}))
```

As I pointed out in the comments it is impossible to store the null byte `\0` in a bash variable, therefore the first entry `${array[0]}` is the empty string.